# trying to build and compile lua 5.3.3 with mingw , undefined reference error

Tags: c, windows, lua

SO basically i got the lua5.3.3 source code and i am trying to build it with mingw

what i have done so far is that i did the whole operation in msys and then copied over the lib files and bin files and include files to mingw appropriate folders

however when i try to actually compile an application that uses it, i get these errors

this is the command i used to compile my program that uses lua

```
gcc syx.cpp -llua

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cckJPF8N.o:syx.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `luaL_newstate()'
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cckJPF8N.o:syx.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `luaL_openlibs(lua_State*)'
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cckJPF8N.o:syx.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `luaL_loadfilex(lua_State*, char const*, char const*)'
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cckJPF8N.o:syx.cpp:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `lua_pcallk(lua_State*, int, int, int, int, int (*)(lua_State*, int, int))'
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cckJPF8N.o:syx.cpp:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `lua_close(lua_State*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and here is the file(very basic) in case you need to see it

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <lua5.3/lua.h>
#include <lua5.3/lualib.h>
#include <lua5.3/lauxlib.h>

/* the Lua interpreter */
lua_State* L;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   L = luaL_newstate();

   luaL_openlibs(L);

   luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua");

   /* cleanup Lua */
   lua_close(L);

        return 0;
}
```

i know the library file exists since it was created with mingw namely liblua.a which sits in my mingw lib folder , as well as the other files related to lua such as lua.exe luac.exe the include files etc so i am not sure what else is missing

Comment: Use `#include "lua.hpp"` instead. It basically does what you're doing below. Also use `g++` if you're compiling c++ code. If you really meant to compile C, then don't use a .cpp extension, use .c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found the solution

turns out gcc is mangling the symbols from the library header(whatever that means)

what needs to be done is the headers need to be wrapped in a extern "C" {//headers} to make it work

reference is here :

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/undefined-reference-error-when-using-lua-api-892782/

and just to be clear, here is a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"{
#include <lua5.3/lua.h>
#include <lua5.3/lualib.h>
#include <lua5.3/lauxlib.h>
}

/* the Lua interpreter */
lua_State* L;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   L = luaL_newstate();

   luaL_openlibs(L);

   luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua");

   /* cleanup Lua */
   lua_close(L);

        return 0;
}
```